# Name of entity is trimmed by JPA tools in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jpa, orm

I am using eclipse version 4.5.0. I have a table in my *postgres* database(version *9.3*) named like **some_table_meas** when I generated entities from tables using JPA tools it generates entity class named **SomeTableMea**. It has removed trailing **s**. What can be the possible issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a "feature" of the Eclipse Dali Entity Generation. It is trying to "singularize" your table name. It even has its own bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346205